# Wrong image dimension from phone gallery

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

In my App, I use the `Xam.Media.Plugin` (from J.Montemagno) to choose images from the gallery or take it with the Phone, using a PopUp. The problem is that if I choose from gallery an image taken by Phone the dimension of the picture is respected; instead if I choose from gallery a photo downloaded from the web the dimension of the picture is not respected.

Some examples: I downloaded a square picture `600x600 px` but if I choose it I see on the display the square picture more or less `200x200 px.` The same with rectangle shape images, `1920x1080` (FHD) images, and so on. Instead, if I take a photo (4:3 or 16:9 is the same) the dimensions are respected.

Moreover, if I try to put the stream into an Image and then modify it setting HeightRequest, WidthRequest, Xamarin ignore my command and I still see the same wrong dimension of the picture.

Can anyone help me?
THX

```
[...]
private async void BtnFoto_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
        var action = await DisplayActionSheet("Choose your Photo", "Back", "", "Gallery", "Take Photo");
        switch (action)
        {
            #region Gallery
            case "Gallery":

                if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsPickPhotoSupported)
                {
                    await DisplayAlert("Alert", "Function not supported", "OK");
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    var file = await CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync(new PickMediaOptions
                    {                            
                        CompressionQuality = 75,
                        CustomPhotoSize = 50,
                        PhotoSize = PhotoSize.MaxWidthHeight, //!!!not working!!!
                        MaxWidthHeight = 2000,
                    }
                    );

                    if (file == null)
                    {
                        return;
                    }

                    else
                    {


                        App.pickedImage.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => file.GetStream());
//some translation that I need, not important for the problem
                        App.pickedImage.TranslationY = 168; //misureGriglia.Height
                        App.pickedImage.TranslationX = 40; //misureGriglia.Width
                        App.pickedImage.MinimumHeightRequest = 280;//!!!not working!!!
                        App.pickedImage.MinimumWidthRequest = 280;//!!!not working!!!

                    }
                }
                break;
            #endregion

            #region TakePhoto
            case "Take Photo": 

                if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
                {
                    await DisplayAlert("Alert", "Camera not suitable", "OK");
                    return;
                }

                var file2 = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions
                {
                    Directory = "Test",
                    SaveToAlbum = true,
                    CompressionQuality = 75,
                    CustomPhotoSize = 50,
                    PhotoSize = PhotoSize.MaxWidthHeight,
                    MaxWidthHeight = 2000,
                    DefaultCamera = CameraDevice.Front
                });

                if (file2 == null)
                    return;
                else
                {

                    App.pickedImage.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => file2.GetStream());
//some translation that I need, not important for the problem
                    App.pickedImage.TranslationY = 168; //misureGriglia.Height
                    App.pickedImage.TranslationX = 40; //misureGriglia.Width


                }

                break;
                #endregion
        }
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new ResizeFoto());
    }
```